# upload multiple photos with ajax, js and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to upload the images to htdocs to save to DB, but it fails. When I use name input = myFile[] I don't know if php gets data using formData or not? The browser always returns me a result that myFile does not exist. If I put input name = myFile it is the same

```
html code
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" >
<form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="form-control col-sm-9" id="filemota" multiple="multiple"/>
<input class="btn col-sm-3" onclick="uploadanhmota()" style="background: #7B68EE;color: white" />
</form>
</div>
```

```
js code
function uploadanhmota() {
            var file_data = $('#filemota').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload2.php', 
                dataType: 'text',  
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                }
            });
    }
```

*code as php not got 1 list image that I have sent by ajax*

```
php code
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_FILES['myFile'])) {
$tmp = array();
$name =  array();
foreach ($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'] as $file1) {
$tmp[] = $file1;
}
foreach ($_FILES['myFile']['name'] as $file2) {
$name[] = $file2;
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp[$i],'./image/' . $name[$i])){
                echo "Tải tập tin thành công";
            }else{
                echo "Tải tập tin thất bại";
            }
        }
   } else {
    die('Lock'); // 
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use submit form to load the page I want to use ajax, I want to send data of the image files, then I will process them in php

Comment: add enctype in your form not on the root div

Comment: I fixed it but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong syntax for sending form data.
Any data you want to send has to have 3 things

1. enclosed by `<form> </form>` tag
2. have a action method (here it should point to you php filename)
3. have method="post" or method="get"

point 4 is not necessary as you are handling it through ajax

4. a submit button

This should solve your problem of data not being sent.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
<form action="your_php_filename" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" class="form-control col-sm-9" id="filemota" name="myFile[]" multiple="multiple"/>
<input class="btn col-sm-3" onclick="uploadanhmota()"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This should solve your problem. Try doing it this way [link]https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: upload images by submit form and load the page I have done and succeed, what I want is to upload multiple images with ajax